# CSS makes text dissapears when I put white color on it

Tags: html, css

```css
.role-card-group {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.role-card {
    height: 200px;
    width: 12%;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.role-card p {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.role-card::before {
    content: '';
    background-color: #007BC7;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.7;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="role-card-group">
    <a href="" class="role-card">
        <p>Cliente</p>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="role-card">
        <p>Corretor</p>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="role-card">
        <p>Parceiro</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

For some reason I think that the before pseudo class is applying opacity on the text and I need the text white inside the card.

Comment: Your pseudo element is in front of the text due to the absolute positioning. This means that your white text is over a white background. I would suggest: `.role-card p { position: relative }`

Comment: That's exactly it! Setting `body { background-color: black; }` makes the issue apparent.

Answer (score 3):

The `::before` psuedoelement is overlapping the paragraph, since it's in position: absolute

Change the stack order by adding `z-index: -1` to `.role-card::before`

```css
.role-card-group {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.role-card {
    height: 200px;
    width: 12%;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.role-card p {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.role-card::before {
    content: '';
    background-color: #007BC7;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.7;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="role-card-group">
    <a href="" class="role-card">
        <p>Cliente</p>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="role-card">
        <p>Corretor</p>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="role-card">
        <p>Parceiro</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

---

Optionally, if you cannot assign a negative z-index to the pseudoelement, you could assign instead a `z-index` to the paragraph (along with a *non-static* position, e.g. `position: relative`)

```css
.role-card-group {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.role-card {
    height: 200px;
    width: 12%;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.role-card p {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.role-card::before {
    content: '';
    background-color: #007BC7;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.7;
    position: absolute;
   
}
```

```html
<div class="role-card-group">
    <a href="" class="role-card">
        <p>Cliente</p>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="role-card">
        <p>Corretor</p>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="role-card">
        <p>Parceiro</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: @Turnip my bad, problem while loading the page. ty.

Comment: One problem with this is that the negative z-index would move the element behind other elements. If `.role-card-group` had a background colour, the pseudo element would be behind it.

Comment: In case they are not able to use a negative z-index I've updated my answer @Turnip

Answer (score 0):

Add `z-index: 9` to `p` or `z-index: -1` to before element  to prevent its overlapping.

```
.role-card-group {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.role-card {
    height: 200px;
    width: 12%;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.role-card p {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    **z-index: 9;**
}

.role-card::before {
    content: '';
    background-color: #007BC7;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.7;
    position: absolute;
}
```